# How to populate a table dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

In my page i have a list and a table,
ex.

```
 <ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Juice</li>
 </ul>

  <form method="post">
   <table id="drinks">
   </table>
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

These are in the same page, What i want to do is when the user select an element(click event) of the list, that element should be included in to the table below without refreshing the page.Later i want the use/itertate thorugh table items(that is the use of the form),Since im new to web developments i don't have good understanding about this. Can anyone help me with this, Thanks

Comment: What part are you stuck on?  What have you tried?

Comment: What information do you want to display on the table? And where will that data come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you'll use JQuery:

```
$('ul>li').click(function(){
    $('form').find('table').append('<tr><td>'+this.innerHTML+'</td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for, small question instead of click  can i use ondblclick to this function when i use it here it doesn't seem to work .

Comment: its `dblclick` not `ondblclick` ;)